# in java8, which class was added as a replacement of `sun.beans.editors.StringEditor`

Tags: java, java-8

I got the class not found error for `sun.beans.editors.StringEditor`, when I was trying to upgrade java6 to java8.

anyone knows which class is imported by java8 to replace this class.

Comment: More to the point, why do you care? Why are you using it in the first place? There has been a warning in place against using `sun.*` classes for 20 years.

Comment: `com.sun.beans.editors.StringEditor` but it could also have been removed...

Comment: But I see `com.sun.beans.editors.StringEditor` in rt.jar(which is still exits in jdk8).

Comment: @AngleTom What I meant is that it could have been removed, but wasn't = you should not count on it being present.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way of acquiring a property editor always was to use

```
PropertyEditor editor = PropertyEditorManager.findEditor(String.class);
```

which will return a JRE and/or configuration specific editor. When you do

```
System.out.println(editor.getClass());
```

you will get `class com.sun.beans.editors.StringEditor` with Oracle’s JDK 1.8 when no additional software has been installed. But there is no reason to ever deal with that class, the method above provides you with a working `PropertEditor` instance. If you need its features for your own property editor, use *delegation*.